# iOS - Display a UIViewController as fullscreen from within a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I need to present a UIViewController as fullscreen (Above all other views). This UIViewController is currently inside a UINavigationController.

Is it possible to have the UINavigationController present it's current top UIViewController modally?

From within the UIViewController I would like to fullscreen, if I use:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Nothing seems to happen.. Is there a reason this is not allowed?

**EDIT**

I have posted another question in which I have solved this issue for every scenario. (Code snippet included there)

[Is it possible for a UIViewController to present itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803773/is-it-possible-for-a-uiviewcontroller-to-present-itself)

Comment: Are you just trying to hide the navigation bar? You could do : [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

Comment: can you share some more code snippet?

Comment: Fraggle: That would work if it wasn't for the fact that I have additional subviews **on top** of the UINavigationController. Thus simply hiding the nav bar will not result in the view I am trying to fullscreen being on top of those other views. This is why I need to present it modally.

Comment: @MichaelCueno can't you just hide those other views? If you could edit your question and add some more details that would help us answer. I'm about to implement something similar and would be happy to help and share.

Comment: That is a possibility, but the project is quite large with many conrtibuters, I think this would be a fragile design as anyone who adds another view would also need to remember to hide it in this function.

Comment: Fraggle: this would be nice, however, my project has other views which are on top of the navigation controller, I would need to hide them all (as user3344977 stated) but this quickly gets complex and fragile. See the post I added to the edit for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this :

```
[self presentViewController:self.navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to show a controller.

Comment: I'm trying to present a UIViewController that is embedded inside the UINavigationController currently, not the navigationController itself. (self refers to the view controller that I need to present)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present a view controller modally, you should be presenting it from a different view controller. The modal presentation will show the presented view controller over the navigation controller (in fullscreen)

For instance,

```
UIViewController *firstVC = self;
UIViewController *secondVC = <the VC you want to present>

[firstVC presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Or just use a modal segue in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the view controller you want to show modally is the navigation controllers top view controller

```
[self presentViewController:self.navigationController.topviewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this fails because the **topViewController** actually _is_ **self**. When I try this code I get the error: `"Application tried to present modally an active controller"`