# Is it possible for a UIViewController to present itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController (lets call it Fred) which may be embedded inside many different types of containers (UINavigationController, UITabBarController, or within a modal). Fred has a button that when tapped, needs to make Fred fullscreen.

Intuitively, this means I would like to present Fred as a fullscreen modal, but there are two problems:

1. Fred is active in the view hierarchy (cannot present a vc that is active)
2. Fred would need to present himself?

I tried to solve this by creating a fullscreenContainerViewController which Fred can call like this:

```
[fullscreenContainer presentViewControllerAsFullscreen:self]
```

Implementation of FullscreenContainerViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIViewController* proxyViewController

// Create a proxy VC to hold state of the original ViewController so that we can safely
// Remove it from it's hierarchy and then restore it after fullscreen is dismissed.
 - (void)presentViewControllerAsFullscreen:(UIViewController*)originalController
{        
    UIViewController* originalParentViewController = originalController.parentViewController;
    UIView* originalSuperview = originalController.view.superview;

    self.proxyViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    self.proxyViewController.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:originalController.view.frame];
    self.proxyViewController.view.autoresizingMask = originalController.view.autoresizingMask;

    // Detach contentController from parent
    [originalController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [originalController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [originalController removeFromParentViewController];

    // Put in the proxy view controller in place of the orignalController
    [originalParentViewController addChildViewController:self.proxyViewController];
    [originalSuperview addSubview:self.proxyViewController.view];
    [self.proxyViewController didMoveToParentViewController:originalParentViewController];
    originalController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.proxyViewController presentViewController:originalController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And then to dismiss:

```
- (void)dismissFullscreenWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
    UIViewController* parentToRestoreTo = self.proxyViewController.parentViewController;
    UIView* superviewToRestoreTo = self.proxyViewController.view.superview;

    [self.proxyViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {

        // Detach proxy view/controller
        [self.proxyViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        [self.proxyViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.proxyViewController = nil;

        // Restore original parent relationship
        [parentToRestoreTo addChildViewController:self.contentController];
        [superviewToRestoreTo addSubview:self.contentController.view];
        [self.contentController didMoveToParentViewController:parentToRestoreTo];
        if (self.shouldRestoreStatusBar) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO                       
                                                    withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        }
    }];
}
```

This works, but it seems anti pattern possibly? Maybe it will break in some subtle way? Is there a better approach to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looks awfully complicated - If your question is if you can pass one instance of a view across several container view controllers - the answer is Yes - Can the same view present itself again in modal form - I don't see why not but  doubt if the same instance of view in 2 different containers is possible - maybe a clone will work

Comment: I don't believe cloning will work, the view and controller I am trying to fullscreen is a WebView/Controller. I don't want to clone it because I need the javascript thread to remain in state. (Cloning it would result in a new javascript thread)

Comment: Fred is just an instance of GuyClass. Make another instance Bob of the same class and let Bob be presented by Fred ...

Comment: For reasons I stated in the last comment, this will not work. Fred's instance must persist.

Comment: perhaps create Fred as a singleton instance that can be referenced as needed. when you segue to another view, you'd have to check to see if the singleton instance exists, and if so, pass it to the presenting viewcontroller

Comment: Interesting idea, but my app needs to have multiple Freds instantiated at any given time.